# Is this pronunciation right?

Tags: pronunciation

Many people in Vietnam pronounce the vowel "e" in "check" as "é" in "écouter" (French), is that correct?

Comment: The sound of the vowel "é" in "écouter" doesn't exist in english, but it is close to the "e" in "check".

Comment: The lax "è" of French _Bibliothèque_ is very close to the lax /ɛ/ in English _check_. The tense "é" of French _écouter_ is very close to the tense /e/ in English _shake_, which does not rhyme with _check_.

Comment: You mean close to "a" in English shake ?

Comment: Yes, that is what he means. Symbols inside slashes (such as /e/) are from the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA). The symbol /e/ means the vowel sound commonly found in words like "shake", "snake", "fate", and "tape". For more information see "What notation and symbols are commonly used here?" at http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

**Check**, rendered in the International Phonetic Alphabet, is: [**[ʧɛk](https://www.ipasource.com/media/ipasource/cms/extra/diction/English%20Charts.pdf)**], whereas **écouter** is [**[ekute](https://www.ipasource.com/media/ipasource/cms/extra/diction/French%20Charts.pdf)**].

[ɛ] is pronounced as in Vietnamese **e** "to fear", and [e] is as in Vietnamese **tê** "numb".

The *ê* in the French word "**bête**" [[bɛt̪](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Fr-b%C3%AAte.ogg)] is a closer bet for **check**.

In Hanoi Vietnamese, the pronunciation of **[sách](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~jkirby/docs/kirby2011vietnamese.pdf)** [sɛk] without the *dấu sắc* (rising accent), is a closer, and perhaps easier model for you. Just change the "s" to the English "ch" sound.

Comment: Well, [e] is't really "ay"; it's tenser than that, or at least it doesn't have a diphthong. And the French *les* isn't really [ɛ] either, it's tenser than [ɛ]. Trying to map French sounds to English is a thankless task.